# Ubuntu Touch how to edit .config files

Tags: ubuntu-touch, configuration, tablet, bq

Trying to edit .config files on BQ tablet but no app associated with this file type and gedit can't find them directly.

Have tried sudo gedit .config but no luck no 'gedit command not found'.

Does anyone know how I can open a .config file and edit it (never used vi)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *Terminal* app.
Navigate to your files, then type `nano filename`. This opens your file in the text editor `nano` and you can make your changes.